# Better management for large number of shared files between TypeScript projects

Tags: visual-studio, typescript

I've been writing bots that run on a platform I do not have control over. Essentially, I can upload a single file, and it only has access to basic JS and the site runtime. I chose to actually develop in TypeScript and transpile, to make things easier (imo). Since the initial bot was written for an individual, I've been asked for a few other customized variants. I do not mind this as there is very little in the bots that need to be changed per person. I have been hardlinking the common files between the projects, so as to not have to update in multiple places. This is, without a doubt, a bad solution. I am developing this in Visual Studio 2015, although I also have Visual Studio Code available, if anyone knows of a better build method. I am not very familiar with either, however. I would prefer being able to keep the common files in one project, and import them as dependencies. Maybe I missed something obvious, but attempting the same as I would do for C# did not seem to work.

Comment: Could you be a bit more specific? You have common js files and other js files that build upon them - right? What do you mean by hardlinking them? Putting them in the same html file with <src> -Tags?

Comment: No not at all. This is a bot that I simply upload a file of onto a site. There's no HTML at all. Hardlinking is a filesystem thing supported by NTFS and some others, it's very similar to Symbolic Linking. It allows a file to only exist once, but appear in a few places, so changes propagate between projects (bot customizations) automatically.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As it turns out, you can declare a tsconfig.json file, and in there, specify things like included directories and specific files. This wound up being exactly what I needed, and was remarkably easy to set up. I've been updated the apps/bots for a while now using this system, and all the common files are effortlessly "shared" between then, with only recompilation necessary.

Answer (score 1):

From the way you are describing things, it sounds like you need to use some sort of custom build.

I would keep each of your bots in the same project and make sure that they share code appropriately, and then after tsc transpiles your files, concatenate them for each bot.  So, each bot will get the files that it needs all stuffed into a single, gargantuan file.

You will need to do some trickiness, like parsing import/require statements, or include some kind of directives in each file that describes what other files are needed.

This doesn't sound too tricky to do and is the approach that I would take given the problem description you have provided.

Comment: I gotta do the same in my typical software development, so I'm quite familiar. I was expecting to need this, but was hoping I just wasn't aware of something.